# С // отобразить сектора матрицы относительно горизонтальной оси

Tags: c, матрицы

нужно отобразить симметрично относительно горизонтальной оси
сектора матрицы, которые лежат выше и ниже главной и
побочного диагоналей, но увы знаю как отображать относительно горизонтальной оси сектора которые лежат правее и левее главной и
побочного диагоналей. может кто помочь?

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (i < (N / 2))
        j_end = i;
    else
        j_end = N - 1 - i;

    for (j = 0; j <= j_end; j++)
    {
        tmp = arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][N - 1 - j];
        arr[i][N - 1 - j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

полный код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 7

int main(void)
{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int arr[N][N];
    int MIN = 0, MAX = 100;
    int i, j, j_end, tmp;

    printf("Initial matrix;\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }




    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (i < (N / 2))
            j_end = i;
        else
            j_end = N - 1 - i;

        for (j = 0; j <= j_end; j++)
        {
            tmp = arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][N - 1 - j];
            arr[i][N - 1 - j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nModified matrix:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Отражение относительно горизонтальной оси подразумевает, что меняются местами строки `i` и `N - 1 - i`. Как для верхнего и нижнего, так и для правого и левого секторов. Если сами диагонали нужно оставить на месте - проверять только на `i==j, i+j==N-1`

В Вашем же коде меняются столбцы, а не строки (т.е. отражение относительно вертикальной оси).

Для верхнего и нижнего секторов:

```
for (i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j <= N - 1 - i; j++) //здесь диагонали включены
    {
        tmp = arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j] = arr[N - 1 - j][j];
        arr[N - 1 - j][j] = tmp;
    }
}
```